# Binary search of a word

Tags: c++

Im very new to programming and I'm currently trying to write a code for binary search of a word in `.txt` file using `vector`. The program checks if the word is found if not the searched word is written to the `.txt` file .The problem is I'm not quite sure I use `std::vector` correctly and I'm almost sure there is a big problem with my `BinarySearch()` function.I have read almost every code on the internet for `binary_search` but I just can't make it work. I can really use some help... The txt file is sorted(one word on each row).The current code finds only 2-3 out of 15 words.Here is my latest attempt:

```
    void BinarySearch(vector<string> cont,string s)
{       
        int middle;
        int first=0;
        int leng=cont.size();
        int last=leng-1;
        bool found=false;



        while(first<=last && !found)
        {
            middle=(first+last)/2;

            if(cont[middle]==s)
            {
            found=true;
            }

            else {

            if(cont[middle]<s)
            {
            last=middle-1;
            }

            else
            {
            first=middle+1;
```

Comment: You can get a lot of help from a tool called a *debugger*.  Single step through the code, statement by statement, *watching* one or more variables.  Let us know which statements are the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were extremely close. But you've got to learn to use the debugger, cause this is a pretty simple catch. This line: `if(container[middle]<search)` is saying:

1. Get `container`'s element at `middle`
2. Compare it to `search`
3. If it comes alphabetically earlier execute the `if`-block, otherwise execute the `else`-block

The `if`-block moves `last` to search the alphabetically earlier `string`s, which is the opposite of what you want. This line should have said:

```
if(container[middle] > search)
```

Here's a Live example of your code working perfectly after I changed that character: http://ideone.com/vvbONO

---

Sounds like this is a programming assignment, in which case your teacher probably wouldn't be happy with you solving it like this, but since you have correctly used a sorted `vector<string>` you can also use: [`binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) to completely replace your `BinarySearch`. Just replace this:

```
BinarySearch(sWord,find);
```

With:

```
cout << (binary_search(cbegin(sWord), cend(sWord), find) ? "word is found" : "Not found") << endl;
```

If you have questions, comment away!

Comment: I have changed the smaller or greater symbol and it still finds only 2-3 words ...Maybe it's something with the txt file although I don't see anything wrong with it :( And I have read this page for binary_search but I don't quite understand how to combine it with the vector in the beginning of the code .Thank you for taking your time to answer and help anyway :)

Comment: @J.Doe So use your debugger and the live example I've linked: http://ideone.com/vvbONO If you can replicate the behavior there then add it to your question. But here's what I suspect: Your `vector` is not sorted. If that's not the case show the `sWord` and `find` contents that cause your `BinarySearch`  to fail in your example. You can also exchange your `BinarySearch` call for the `binary_search` line we all know is correct. see if your answers differ.

Comment: Yes ,I finally figured it out and managed ,I thought that I should only make my text file that has one word on one row in the beginning. I sorted the vector and now works perfectly.Thank you !

Comment: Hey I just wanted to say good job on the code. You basically had it, in fact with just a little debugging you didn't need me at all. Hopefully you are using Visual Studio, it's debugging s very simple and straight forward. They've got a nice guide here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I don't .In fact our teacher has forbidden the use of any IDE that's why I was always a little afraid of using debugger (mainly because what he had showed us once,looked very complicated at that time,as stupid as it sounds).But I will start using it from now on,so I manage with simple mistakes like this one.Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: @J.Doe That's unfortunate, I'd consider training you not to use an IDE as a disservice. But it can't be helped now.. If you're on Windows, Visual Studio 2015 Community is pretty great, and free. Get it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs On Linux I tend to use Eclipse, but it frustrates me some, so perhaps there's something better out there.